# Treeview Tooltip behaves weird when the window is created programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

When I add my treeview to a window that I created programtically, the tooltip only shows when the cursor was on a node that had a tooltip as well before it enters the node.

```
class Program
{
    private static Form window;
    private static TreeView treeView;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitialiseComponent();
        window.ShowDialog();
    }

    private static void InitialiseComponent()
    {
        window = new Form();

        treeView = new TreeView(){ShowNodeToolTips = true};

        TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode { Text = "node1", ToolTipText = "node1Tooltip" };
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode { Text = "node2", ToolTipText = "node2Tooltip" };
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode { Text = "node3" };

        TreeNode node11 = new TreeNode { Text = "node1.1" };
        TreeNode node21 = new TreeNode { Text = "node2.1", ToolTipText = "node2.1Tooltip" };
        TreeNode node22 = new TreeNode { Text = "node2.2"};
        node1.Nodes.Add(node11);
        node2.Nodes.Add(node21);
        node2.Nodes.Add(node22);

        treeView.Nodes.Add(node1);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(node2);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(node3);

        window.Controls.Add(treeView);
    }
}
```

You need to add windows form as a reference to the project to test this.
The hover works properly if you add the treeview to a window that was created with the default windows forms project.

Try to hover over node 2 directly without your cursor being over a node before entering.

Then move your mouse up to node 1 and then back to node 2. the tooltip will show if your cursor was over a node that has a tooltip before.

**Why?** How can I fix this/make it work?

Comment: Add `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` as the first line of your `Main` method.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Oh wow that worked. Put that as awser. But why dose that work?

Comment: I don't have any idea about *Why*. I tried missing things like `[STAThread]` attribute individually and by adding `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` the problem solved.

Comment: @RezaAghaei ok well. Should i post the  awnser then?

Comment: Yes, you can post it as answer as it's acceptable for *How can I fix this/make it work?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Application.EnableVisualStyles(); as the first line of your Main method. No idea why!